# Is JavaScript/ECMAScript a Regular Language?

Tags: javascript, regex, language-agnostic

I've tried a few google searches, and I cannot come up with any articles/previous questions that address this.  The reason is a minor dispute I'm having with someone about using input validation to reject possible XSS.  I know for a fact that HTML isn't a regular language, but I can't make that argument quite as strongly for javascript.

I checked this link:

http://www.dlsi.ua.es/~mlf/nnafmc/pbook/node46.html

And I've come up with this:  Since tags in html can be infinitely nested, that's an intuitive notion as to why HTML is NOT a regular language.  By extension, since you can infinitely nest blocks of JavaScript code with `{}`, then javascript too is NOT a regular language.

I'd like to see a more formal presentation either for or against this informal proposition.  Or maybe even a discussion about regex extensions in programming languages that *perhaps* make it possible to do this kind of thing without writing a parser.

Comment: Any syntax that's got anything like parentheses and arithmetic expressions is not going to be a regular grammar.

Comment: Also XSS protection isn't about *input* validation, it's about sanitization of *output*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not practical programming. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Flagged question to be moved.  (More helpful than voting to close.)

Comment: @pointy yes, we're already covering output escaping, but we want a validation filter on the front so we can log suspicious activity.

Comment: This is also to prove why validation alone isn't sufficient.  My work friend thinks we can call all data golden if we only validate it.

Comment: @avgvstvs ah. Well, be confident that your work friend is incorrect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, JavaScript is not a regular language, which can be proved with the fact that braces must be balanced as your intuition suggested.

A useful tool for demonstrating that languages are not regular is the [Pumping Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). You can use it to demonstrate that if JavaScript was regular, some sequence like

```
function(){ function() { function(){ ... function () {
```

(in which `{` are not matched) could be repeated any number of times when surrounded by a certain prefix and suffix, which is in obviously in contradiction with the fact that curly braces must be matched.

Comment: Pumping lemma gives me exactly what I was looking for, thanks!